# Snowflake Tasks and Streams - Complexity and Visualization

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We're heading into a POC and would need to determine if Snowflake tasks and streams are useful for CDC and data transformation. I have read snowflake documentation and the more I read it seems like it will be a complex mess to handle. Thinking about thousands of tables and complex transformations, how will tasks and streams scale up? Considering of a table that gets loaded from 5 other feeds, how will the process look like. On top of that, snowflake doesn't offer any visualization to work with tasks. Can some of you who worked with Snowflake streams/tasks comment and share you opinion of using tasks and streams? If you went with an alternative after trying them out, was it a commercial ETL tool or databricks? If we're already using qlik to bring in data into AWS S3 (data lake), would it make sense to use streams to ingest from our data lake into snowflake?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

This question seems too wide for the typical Stack Overflow process (so the community might choose to close it).

In the meantime, I'll reply here to one of the stated questions: "On top of that, snowflake doesn't offer any visualization to work with tasks"

There is a tool to visualize tasks, created by a Snowflake SE:

https://medium.com/snowflake/visualizing-task-hierarchies-and-dependencies-in-snowflake-snowsight-d28298d0f0ed

[image]

[image]

For the larger picture: Snowflake streams and tasks are basic building blocks for more complex solutions. As your use case grows more complex, you'll need to find ways to manage this complexity - either with your own tools, Snowflake's, or third parties.

Since you are running a POC: Make sure to ask your Snowflake sales contact. Engineers like Dave are ready and eager to find a solution that fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look at snowsight. I was trying to gather insights from folks who use streams and tasks with thousands of them running complex workloads. Any insights on those additional tools/ 3rd party connectors would help.